# .NET master page equivalent in Angular with external html pages

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, master-pages

Our current application is ASP.NET Webforms, and we're planning on migrating it to Angular and ASP.NET Core.

As POC, I'm trying to figure out how we can maintain existing structure. Our header and footer are designed by a different team and they are currently referenced in the master pages via the `header.html` and `footer.html` files from a separate folder supplied by this team. Unfortunately this process won't change with move to Angular.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to integrate existing html pages in an angular component but I haven't come across any good tutorial / examples for this.

I tried to add the link to files in template url for header/footer components I created but I get an error:

> Error NG5002: Unexpected character "EOF"

There's nothing but regular html markup in these files.

I cannot touch these html pages (either content or even where they are deployed in IIS) as they're created by a different team and they have the freedom to make changes as they see fit (header has links to different services/offerings/clients and these get frequent updates)

If Angular doesn't provide this functionality, the alternative I'm thinking is to have a layout built in ASP.NET Core MVC and plug-in the Angular application into it. Header and footer can continue to be referenced from the pages built by external devs and we'll still only be responsible for our Angular section

Comment: it'll be fairly simple since angular uses standard HTML anyway.   After using the ng generate component command to create .html, .ts, and .css files, you can copy/paste the HTML into the created .html file.  You'll then take control of all the events in your .ts file... or via router links.  (So some adjustments to the standard HTML would be needed for event driven things... for example to tie a click event to a function in .ts file or to add a [routerLink] that's defined in routing/app module...)

Comment: each component will have a 'selector' defined which you can use to insert it into other pages... ex: header's .ts file might have: selector: 'app-header'.  You can then insert that into any page via <app-header>//might have loading indicator here</app-header>  If you go Angular, it's going to take care of all the front-end stuff... you won't need the back-end to handle any of that.... it just needs to return data.

Comment: Sorry if this wasn't clear. I cannot copy/paste the html other team generates. They do it on their own schedule and we simply reference it. Any changes we make requires a whole production release cycle which is still a cumbersome process on our end

Comment: If there are any links, they'd need to be adjusted to a new scheme.  You'll also need those files to be apart of the angular build.  Remember that angular will build one single page, usually "index.html", along with .js and .css files.

Comment: there is one way to go here, which would be to call those pages from a service... the service would normally return something like JSON, but you could just return the HTML (the static file would do that anyway, so no changes needed), and populate the DOM, then add event handlers jQuery style (do not use jQuery though... use vanilla JS).  This is not recommended as Angular works more like asp.net (with controller, model(s), view), but might be a temporary workaround until you switch your build processes fully.